# Variable argument macro to define splitting polynomial

Tags: macros, arguments, variable, polynomials, listofitems

I need a macro that behaves the following:

`\mpoly{x}{1}{2}` outputs (x+1)(x+2)

`\mpoly{x}{1}{2}{3}` outputs (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)

`\mpoly{x}{1}{2}{3}{5}` outputs (x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+5)

and so on. I am not at all confident with the variable length argument processing by tex. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Will the arguments of `\mpoly` always be either a single letter or a single number, or could they be more general inputs? And how is LaTeX supposed to "know" if some argument in curly braces is (a) still another argument of `\mpoly` or (b) some other document element?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I streamline the syntax by putting all the term data in a comma separated list in the 2nd argument.  I use `listofitems` to parse the list (the default list separtor is a comma, but that could be changed).  The package's `\foreachitem` macro allows easy regurgitation.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mpoly[2]{%
  \readlist\myterms{#2}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\myterms{(#1+\x)}%
}
\begin{document}
$y_1 =\mpoly{x}{1,2}$

$y_2 =\mpoly{x}{1,2,3}$

$y_3 = \mpoly{x}{1,2,3,5}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be generalized to a more inclusive format, with the use of nested parsing, to allow multiple variables as well as setting the +/- operation:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\newcommand\mpoly[1]{%
  \setsepchar{*/+||-/,}
  \readlist\myterms{#1}%
  \foreachitem\x\in\myterms[]{
    \foreachitem\y\in\myterms[\xcnt,2]{(\myterms[\xcnt,1]\mytermssep[\xcnt,1]\y)}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
$y_1 =\mpoly{x+1,2 * y-3,4}$

$y_2 =\mpoly{x+2,3 * x-4,5,6,7}$

$y_3 = \mpoly{x-1,2 * y+3,5 * z-6}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Very nice use of the `listofitems` package!

Comment: @mxant I have generalized the solution.

Comment: @Mico I made it even nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Different syntax could be more flexible:

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand*\mpoly[2]{\foreach\x in{#2}{(#1\x)}}
```

That would let you do `\mpoly{x-}{1,2,3}` or `\mpoly{x+}{2,...,5}`.

Another option could be

```
\newcommand*\mpolyn[3]{\foreach\x in{#3}{(#1#2\x)}}
```

That would let you do `\mpolyn x-{1,2,3}` or `\mpolyn x+{2,...,5}`. Or may be cleaner definition for this last synax

```
\newcommand\mpolyn{}
\protected\def\mpolyn#1#{\mpolynaux{#1}}
\protected\def\mpolynaux#1#2{\foreach\x in{#2}{(#1\x)}}
```

And that way you can `\mpolyn xyz - {1,2,3}` or `\mpolyn \ln(x) + {2,...,5}` for instance.